# Delete all item contains word with regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
List = ['aleksandre', 'shopify-ecommerce', 'php-ecommerce', 'html-code', 'css-code', 'sultan', 'november']


New List = ['aleksandre', 'sultan', 'november']
```

How I can delete item contains `'ecommerce'` and `'code'` from list?

I try to delete with regex but i cant.

Comment: How did you try to delete the items?

Comment: Please include the code that you are attempting to do this with.

Comment: *I try to delete with regex but i cant.* - If you do it right it works. Show some code. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
List = ['aleksandre', 'shopify-ecommerce', 'php-ecommerce', 'html-code', 'css-code', 
'sultan', 'november']
a = [ x for x in List if "ecommerce" not in x  and  "code" not in x]
print(a)
```

output is:

```
['aleksandre', 'sultan', 'november']
```

Comment: it works thank you.

Comment: your welcome, Could you please vote for my answer?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: everyone can ask a question and accept one answer and earns a scholar badge. Without having scores.

Comment: @Blackwindow11 You can always [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) an answer, irrespective of your rep.

Comment: Thank you so much @Blackwindow11